# Git rebase and children branches

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have the following situation, on my project

```
Master M1----M2----M3----M4----M5
                     \
                 Beta B1----B2----B3---B4
                                   \
                          Feature   F1---F2---F3
```

I am developing in `Feature`, but a really important update was released on commit `M5`, and I don't want to detach `Feature` from `B3` (`Feature` depends on `B1` and `B2`), and `Beta` can have the change (no difference for `Beta`).

If I make a `git rebase Master` on `Beta`, it would only move the `Beta` branch, right (no changes applied on `Feature`)? Or it would end up like this (Below - changes also applied on `Feature`)?

```
Master M1----M2----M3----M4----M5
                                 \
                             Beta B1----B2----B3---B4
                                               \
                                      Feature   F1---F2---F3
```

And, to be like this (changes applied on `Feature`), what should I do? That is my desired state...

Comment: 1. Right, Operations on `Beta` do not affect `Feature`. 2. Do the rebase in `Feature` branch directly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are correct: running `git rebase Master` while on `Beta` will not affect `Feature`.  (Aside: why the uppercase letters?)

The fundamental issue here is that `git rebase` "means" *copy some commits*.  The trick is seeing which commits get copied, to where, and what happens to the branch names afterward.  If the commits that were copied, are also reachable from some *other* branch, the originals—before copying—remain reachable from that other branch.

Remember that all branch names are merely pointers, pointing to the most recent commit on the branch.  All earlier parent commits are on that branch, even if those earlier commits are also on other branches too.  So "all `Beta` commits" includes `M1` through `M3` initially.

So, how does the first `git rebase` know to copy *only* `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, and `B4`?  I think one key item is to draw the graph a bit differently:

```
M1----M2----M3----M4----M5   <-- Master
              \
               B1----B2----B3---B4   <-- Beta
                            \
                             F1---F2---F3   <-- Feature
```

To see what will get copied, take a green highlighter to the tip commit of the branch, i.e., `B4` as pointed-to by `Beta`, and color all commits green as you follow the lines towards the left.  That includes commits `M3` and earlier.  Then, take a *red* highlighter to the tip commit of `Master` (that's M5), and color all commits *red* as you follow the lines to the left.  The red over-paints the green, so that `M3` and earlier are not considered for copying.  This leaves exactly the right set of commits to copy.

The copies themselves land after the tip commit of the argument.  That's `Master`, so the copies come after `M5`.

After Git does the copying, Git moves the name `Beta` to point to the copy of `B4`, which we will call `B4'`.  That leaves the original `Bn` commits dangling ... except that `B3` is reachable from `F1`:

```
                          B1'---B2'---B3'--B4'   <-- Beta
                         /
M1----M2----M3----M4----M5   <-- Master
              \
               B1----B2----B3---B4   [no name]
                            \
                             F1---F2---F3   <-- Feature
```

So that's all fine for `Beta`, but now you would like to copy `Feature`'s commits.  If you:

```
git checkout Feature
git rebase Beta
```

Git will color `F3` green, then `F2` and `F1` ... but then go on to mark `B3` back through `B1` green as well.  Only the *copies* `B1'`, `B2'`, `B3'`, `B4'`, and the five `M` commits, get colored or overwritten with red.  So Git will copy too many commits.

The solution is to use `git rebase --onto <name>`.  Adding `--onto` tells Git where to put the copies: you want them to go after `B4'`, so you can say `--onto Beta` to say that the copies go after Beta, i.e., `B4'`.

That doesn't actually *fix* anything ... yet.  But it frees up the *other* argument, the one that *was* `Beta`, to be, well, something else.

What you want is to tell Git where to start marking commits red.  That's `B3`, or if it's easier, `B4`.  That will mark `B3` and all its earlier commits (including `M3` and earlier too) red: do not copy.

You can use the raw ID of `B3`, if you save it.  Or you can easily have Git look up the *previous* tip of `Beta` using `Beta@{1}`:

```
git rebase --onto Beta Beta@{1}
```

This finds the hash ID of commit `B4` using the reflog for `Beta`.

Comment: Beautifully explained. If _copies_ in paragraph "_Git will color..._" means `B1'`, `B2'`, `B3'` and `B4'`, it should be clearer.

Comment: @randvir: it says what I meant it to say, but I agree it can be improved a bit. I've made an attempt at that now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it would end up with something like this:

```
Master M1----M2----M3----M4----M5
                    \            \
                     \       Beta B1----B2----B3---B4
                      \
                       \--B1'---B2'---B3'----F1---F2---F3
                                                       ^
                                                    feature
```

Basically, your rebase for `Beta` will reapply the commits on Beta on top of the current tip of master. However, the original commits will still exist and if anything else, such as another branch, are referring to those commits, they will still persist.

You would need to first rebase `Beta` and then rebase `feature` in order to move everything "into the correct place".